# Caching in A BlackBerry application

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I've implemented a set of methods to cache data, but it does not seem to work in BlackBerry (works OK in Android and iOS).

I am using Cordova FileSystem API and WebWorks for debugging.
Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

**Saving Cache:**

```
saveCache: function(fileName, data, writeEnd, onFail){// Takes Two parameters ;the fileName that will be generated and its content (JSON format : Adapter Result)
            if (typeof LocalFileSystem != 'undefined') {

                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 1024 * 1024, gotFS, fail);//Invoking Cordova's FileSystem

                function gotFS(fileSystem) {
                    fileSystem.root.getFile(fileName, {create: true}, gotFileEntry, fail);//Creating Cache File named fileName
                    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
                        fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);//Calling the fileWriter , if Success it writes the data into the file, If failure calls fail method to display the error
                    }
                    function gotFileWriter(writer) {
                        writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
                            console.log("Write Ended");
                            writeEnd();
                        };


                           writer.write(Base64.encode(data));// Writing data  


                    }
                }
```

**Loading From Cache**

```
loadCache: function(filename, loadEnd, onFail){
            if (typeof LocalFileSystem != 'undefined') {

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 1024 * 1024, gotFS, fail);

                function gotFS(fileSystem) {
                    fileSystem.root.getFile(filename, { create: false }, gotFileEntry, fail);
                    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
                        fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
                    }
                    function gotFile(file){
                        readAsText(file);
                    }
                    function readAsText(file) {
                        var reader = new FileReader();

                        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                            console.log("Read as text");
                            //console.log(Base64.decode(evt.target.result));   
                            alert(evt.target.result);
                            loadEnd(Base64.decode(evt.target.result));
                        };
                        reader.readAsText(file);

                    }
                }
                function fail(evt) {
                    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
                    onFail();
                }
            }else{
                onFail();
            }
        },
```